# Ruby on Rails friends list feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new here and I thought I could ask a topic about creating a friend's list for users in my small rails project, since I couldn't find an answer specific enough to what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to make a basic friend request, so that I can have users in a database use a 'friend' function to keep track of players they like, so that they can keep in contact, etc. I currently am thinking that I need to use a has_many relation in regards to setting things up, but I'm not quite sure where to take it from there, besides just having each user have a list of names they wish to keep. If that's how it's done, how would I code that so each user has a list of users they wish to keep, as well as remove, add, email, etc?

Comment: I think you'd be well served by Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, which walks through building a Twitter clone and discusses the 'friend' function and self-referential associations in depth. It is available to read for free online: https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much complete and complex you want to implement it into your project.

You may want to use a gem, like [amistad](https://github.com/raw1z/amistad) or [has_friendship](https://github.com/sungwoncho/has_friendship), which are plain simple to install and use. You also have [socialization](https://github.com/cmer/socialization), which has a follow/mention/like usage like Twitter does.

If you want to learn how to code that from scratch (e.g. educational purposes), [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=comments) is pretty good at explaining how to implement that feature.

And if you want something even more complex, you have some gems that gives you features that you usually have at a social network (friends, photos, personal blogs and so on...): [social_stream](https://github.com/ging/social_stream) or [diaspora](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora)